How can I evaluate this sum? $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\psi^{(1)}(n + 1) \psi(n)}{n^2}$

Question

How can I evaluate this sum?
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\psi^{(1)}(n + 1)  \psi(n)}{n^2}$$

$$\textbf{My attempt}$$

\begin{align*}
S &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\psi^{(1)}(n + 1)  \psi(n)}{n^2} \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\psi^{(1)}(n + 1) (H_{n-1} - \gamma)}{n^2} \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\psi^{(1)}(n + 1)  H_{n-1}}{n^2} - \gamma \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\psi^{(1)}(n + 1)}{n^2} \\
&= S_1 - \gamma S_2 \\
S_1 &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\psi^{(1)}(n + 1) H_{n-1}}{n^2} \\
&= -\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(x)}{1 - x} \left( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n H_{n-1}}{n^2} \right) dx
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
\text{We know} \quad \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^{n-1} H_{n-1} &= -\frac{\ln(1-x)}{1-x} \\
\Rightarrow \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n} H_{n-1}}{n} &= \frac{1}{2} \ln^2(1-x) = -\text{Li}_2(1-x) - \text{Li}_2(x) \ln(1-x) \\
&\quad + \ln(1-x)\left(x^2 - 3\ln(1-x)\ln(x)\right) + 3
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
\Rightarrow S_1 &=  \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(x)}{1 - x} \, dx + \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(x)  \text{Li}_{3}(1 - x)}{1 - x} \, dx \\
&\quad + \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(x)  \text{Li}_{2}(x)  \ln(1 - x)}{1 - x} \, dx \\
&\quad - \frac{\pi^2}{6} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(x)  \ln(1 - x)}{1 - x} \, dx + \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln^2(x) \ln^2(1-x)}{1 - x} \, dx
\end{align*}
The first Integral is $-\zeta(3)$
I am completely stuck on how to evaluate the last four integrals. I know the evaluation of $S_2$—it's very easy; it's $\pi^4/120$.
I welcome any new methods to evaluate $S$.

I think it's easier to use $\psi^{(1)}(n+1)=2H_n^{(2)}-2\zeta(2)$ as this way leads you to well known sums.
